# What's wrong with this Reat Todo List?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have been trying to make a todo list in React to apply what I have been learning, but I can't seem to get it working. Below is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
class TodoForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { todos: [" test "], add: "Text" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ add: event.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.push(this.state.add) });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form name="todo-list" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="todo-input" value={this.state.add} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" text="Add" />
        </form>
        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TodoForm />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I am expecting to enter in a value then click submit and it will add the value to the list, preferably without a reload but at the moment all I want is for it to work. I think it has something to do with the adding to the array, as the map function displays the dummy 'test' value.

I originally didn't have a handleChange but have tried adding that to keep updating the add variable with the text fields value, and then when submit is pressed to add to the todos variable using setState. I have tried everything I can think of and would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the next method:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.push(this.state.add) });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

`this.state.todos.push(this.state.add)` returns the new length of the array not the array itself. So in order to fix this we can use destructuring. We substitute it for:

```
[...this.state.todos, this.state.add]
```

which will return a new array with the old values and the new one.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use destructuring you can do the following:

```
this.state.todos.concat(this.state.add)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this worked! That actually makes so much sense about .push() returning array length.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the cuplrit:

```
todos: this.state.todos.push(this.state.add)
```

`Array.push()` returns the new length of the array so it will be an `number` and thus `this.state.todos` is not an array anymore and thus breaks the UI.

You can do this instead:

```
todos: [...this.state.todos, this.state.add]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, I appreciate it a lot!